# How to Implement a multidimensional array if the dimension is unknown at compile-time?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I want to implement a function that gets as a parameter a dimension "n" of an array of integers. This function also gets values "k_1, k_2, ..., k_n" defining the size of the array. Then this function will fill this n-dimensional array.

How do I implement this efficiently with C++?

For example for n = 3 I would use

```
vector < vector < vector < int > > > array;
```

But I don't know the dimension at compile time.

Comment: If n is your dimension, k_1...k_n is not nearly enough data.

Comment: Are n-dimensional arrays part of the problem or the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a one-dimensional array, and fake the other dimensions using multiplication of offsets for indexing, and you can pass the dimension sizes in by vector, i.e.

```
std::vector<int> create_md_array(const std::vector<int> & dimensions)
{
    int size = std::accumulate(dimensions.begin(), dimensions.end(), 1, std::multiplies<int>());
    return std::vector<int>(size);
}
```

Comment: Nice idea. You can then extend `std::vector<int>` for providing some syntax sugar for getting and setting an element of this array (for example overloading `operator()`)

Comment: @Murilo: I would not extend `vector`.  This would be wrapped in a separate class.

Comment: I actually implemented a N-dimensional array in cpp. This is what I did.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of choices. You can implement it yourself, basically multiplying the coordinates by the sizes to linearize the multi-dimensional address, and just have a simple `std::vector<whatever>` to hold the data.

Alternatively, you could use `std::valarray` and friends to accomplish the same. It has a set of classes that are specifically intended for the kind of situation you describe -- but they're used so rarely that almost nobody understands them. Writing the code yourself stands a good chance of being easier for most people to read and understand.